# Finding the Variance of the MLE Variance of a Joint Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood, estimators

I have a random sampling of $Z_1,...Z_n$ from a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. I am considering them within a joint likelihood function.

I know that the MLE ($\hat\sigma^{2}$) of $\sigma^{2}$ is $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}$.

I want to find the variance of $\hat\sigma^{2}$.

Here is my reasoning so far:

I know that

$
\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} \sim \chi^{2}_{n-1}\\
\implies \frac{n\hat\sigma^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} \sim \chi^{2}_{n-1} \\
\therefore \text{Var}(\frac{n\hat\sigma^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}) = 2(n-1)$ 
Here, I guessed that I need to make the assumption that $\sigma^{2}$ is a constant.
$\frac{n^{2}}{\sigma^{4}}\text{Var}(\hat\sigma^{2}) = 2(n-1) \\
\therefore \text{Var}(\hat\sigma^{2}) = \frac{2(n-1)\sigma^{4}}{n^{2}}
$

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I need to make the assymption that $\sigma^2$ is constant" ? Are you considering it to be a random variable ? If you are not doing Bayesian statistics, $\sigma^2$ is usually constant (just unknown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved much more generally for any distribution whose moments exist. Let $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ denote a random sample of size $n$ drawn from a population random variable $X$. By definition, your MLE estimator is the $2^\text{nd}$ *sample central moment*:

$$m_2 = \frac1n \sum _{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}\right){}^2$$

The problem is to find:  $\text{Var}(m_2)$ .

**Background**

The problem is just a special case of the much more general problem of 'moments of moments' which are usually defined in terms of power sum notation:

$$s_r=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r$$

The *first* step is to express the sample central moment $m_2$ in terms of  power sums $s_i$. This is a well-known result, but for generality is done here by the *mathStatica* function `SampleCentralToPowerSum[r]`:

[image]

We seek $\text{Var}(m_2)$ ... *i.e.* the $2^\text{nd}$ `CentralMoment` of $m_2$. The solution can be obtained with the `mathStatica` function:

[image]

where the solutions is expressed in terms of central moments of the population $\mu_i$, assuming they exist of course.

**Special case of Normality**

The above is a completely general solution for any distribution whose moments exist. In the special case of a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ parent, we have that $\mu_2 = \sigma^2$  and  $\mu_4 = 3\sigma^4$, which simplifies to:

[image]